# How to replace the multiple column value of a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have done this by using

```
df.withColumn('username1', regexp_replace(col('username1'), 'Me', 'My')).withColumn('username2', regexp_replace(col('username2'), 'Me', 'My')).withColumn('username3', regexp_replace(col('username3'), 'Me', 'My'))
```

But I saw only it got reflect on `username` column other 2 columns(`username2`,and `username3`) not affected by this.

Comment: so you want to replace every occurrence of "Me" by "My" in your columns. Are you sure that all three columns of yours have "Me" in it?

Comment: yes sure name 1, name2 ,name 3 update the question

Comment: Not able to reproduce same error on my end :( btw which version of spark are u using?

Comment: spark 2.2 glue 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the error at my side. Follows a sample code that is working for me.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schemaString = "username email ph"
val fields = schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,StringType, nullable=true))

val schema = StructType(fields)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("me_name,me_name@yahoo.com,me_phone")).map(_.split(",")).map{x => org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x:_*)}

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

val newDF = df.withColumn("username", regexp_replace(col("username"), "me", "my")).withColumn("email", regexp_replace(col("email"), "me", "my")).withColumn("ph", regexp_replace(col("ph"), "me", "my"))
```

See the actual data in the dataframe

```
df.show
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|username|            email|      ph|
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| me_name|me_name@yahoo.com|me_phone|
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

Now let's see the transformed data

```
newDF.show
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|username|            email|      ph|
+--------+-----------------+--------+
| my_namy|my_namy@yahoo.com|my_phone|
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

Let me know if that helps.